# Printing PDF files with VBA

Tags: vba, vbscript

I am new to coding with VBA. This is my unfinished code to print documents in a folder containing documents with 3 distinct headers, "DN" "INV" and "PO". I've been searching around for the code/method to print out PDF documents. I tried using the invokeverb "&print" function but it doesn't seem to work. Can someone please teach me how to print it out? Thank you very much :)

P.S. "DN" needs to printed out once, " INV" needs to be printed out 6 times, "PO" needs to be printed out 2 times.

```
'' To set the path to the current folder

set shApp = CreateObject("shell.application")

currentPath = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetAbsolutePathName(".") 

set shFolder = shApp.NameSpace( currentPath )

'' To set the items in the current folder as "files"

set files = shFolder.Items()

''Start of code''

'msgbox("Starting Script")

for each files in files

        ' If name contains "DN" '
        if inStr(files, "DN") then
            'print out 1 time'
        end if
        ' if name contains "INV" '
        if inStr(files, "INV") then
            'print out 6 times'
        end if
        ' if name contains "PO" '
        if inStr(files, "PO") then
            'print out 2 times'
        end if
next
MsgBox("completed")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo,

I found this: https://www.ozgrid.com/forum/forum/help-forums/excel-general/90407-printing-a-file-using-vba-code

```
Option Explicit

Declare Function apiShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "ShellExecuteA" (    ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal lpOperation As String, ByVal lpFile As String, _    ByVal lpParameters As String, ByVal lpDirectory As String, ByVal nShowCmd As Long) As Long

Public Sub PrintFile(ByVal strPathAndFilename As String)

   Call apiShellExecute(Application.hwnd, "print", strPathAndFilename, vbNullString, vbNullString, 0)

End Sub

Sub Test()

   PrintFile ("C:\Test.pdf")

End Sub
```

But this only let's you print on your default printer.

I tested it. It works:

```
Declare Function apiShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "ShellExecuteA" ( _
   ByVal hwnd As Long, _
   ByVal lpOperation As String, _
   ByVal lpFile As String, _
   ByVal lpParameters As String, _
   ByVal lpDirectory As String, _
   ByVal nShowCmd As Long) _
   As Long

Public Sub PrintFile(ByVal strPathAndFilename As String)

   Call apiShellExecute(Application.hwnd, "print", strPathAndFilename, vbNullString, vbNullString, 0)

End Sub

Sub PrintPDF()

'' To set the path to the current folder

Set shApp = CreateObject("shell.application")

'currentPath = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetAbsolutePathName(".")
currentPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path

Set shFolder = shApp.Namespace(currentPath)

'' To set the items in the current folder as "files"

Set Files = shFolder.Items()

''Start of code''

'msgbox("Starting Script")

For Each file In Files
   If InStr(file, ".pdf") Then
       ' If name contains "DN" '
       If InStr(file, "DN") Then
           PrintFile (currentPath + "\" + file)
       End If
       ' if name contains "INV" '
       If InStr(file, "INV") Then
           For i = 1 To 6
               PrintFile (currentPath + "\" + file)
           Next i
       End If
       ' if name contains "PO" '
       If InStr(file, "PO") Then
               PrintFile (currentPath + "\" + file)
               PrintFile (currentPath + "\" + file)
       End If
   End If
Next
MsgBox ("completed")

End Sub
```

So, after correcting a mistake, that it is VBS and not VBA i suggest this code:

```
Set shApp = CreateObject("shell.application")

Set shFolder = shApp.Namespace(currentPath)

'' To set the items in the current folder as "files"

Set Files = shFolder.Items()

''Start of code''

For Each file In Files
If InStr(file, ".pdf") Then
   ' If name contains "DN" '
   If InStr(file, "DN") Then
       file.InvokeVerbEx("Print")
       WScript.Sleep 1000 'wait 1 sec
   End If
   ' if name contains "INV" '
   If InStr(file, "INV") Then
       Filename = currentPath + "\" + file
       Do
           i = i+1
           file.InvokeVerbEx("Print") 
           WScript.Sleep 1000 'wait 1 sec
       Loop until i >=6
       i = 0
   End If
   ' if name contains "PO" '
   If InStr(file, "PO") Then
       Filename = currentPath + "\" + file
           file.InvokeVerbEx("Print") 
           WScript.Sleep 1000 'wait 1 sec
           file.InvokeVerbEx("Print") 
           WScript.Sleep 1000 'wait 1 sec
    End If
End If
Next
MsgBox ("completed")
```

Comment: Hi Kajkrow, Thank you for your help. However, Im so sorry. I found out why your code couldn't work. Im doing this on vbs (using notepad ++ ) and not VBA. sorry for the amateur mistake...

Answer (score 2):

The VBA code from Kajkrow works well. I needed to print to specific printer, so, if someone is looking at this, I found a solution that worked for me, simple use "printto" instead of "print" as the verb of ShellExecute, and provide the name of the specific printer name in the fourth parameter just after the filename.

```
Call apiShellExecute(Application.hwnd, "printto", strPathAndFilename, "my printer name", vbNullString, 0)
```

Comment: I know this is from a while ago but I'm getting an error when using this saying printer information not found.  I've tried typing the printer name in multiple times and was wondering how the printer name is supposed to look.  Is it the IP? This printer is on a network with multiple computer connections if that changes anything.

Comment: You should look at the printer name on windows control panel. There is the name of each printer, right the same you must use here, at least so worked for me.