# Printing PDF files using VBS

Tags: vbscript

I am new to coding with VBS. This is my unfinished code to print documents in a folder containing documents with 3 distinct headers, "DN" "INV" and "PO". I've been searching around for the code/method to print out PDF documents. I tried using the invokeverb "&print" function but it doesn't seem to work. Can someone please teach me how to print it out? Thank you very much :)

"DN" needs to printed out once, " INV" needs to be printed out 6 times, "PO" needs to be printed out 2 times.

P.S. Thank you @kajkrow for solving this same problem using VBA. Reposting as I found out I was using VBS. Previous question can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50906669/printing-pdf-files-with-vba/50907072#50907072). *EDIT : attached link solves my problem in both VBA and VBS and uses InvokeVerbEx to print files.

```
'' To set the path to the current folder

set shApp = CreateObject("shell.application")

currentPath = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetAbsolutePathName(".") 

set shFolder = shApp.NameSpace( currentPath )

'' To set the items in the current folder as "files"

set files = shFolder.Items()

''Start of code''

'msgbox("Starting Script")

for each files in files

        ' If name contains "DN" '
        if inStr(files, "DN") then
            'print out 1 time'
        end if
        ' if name contains "INV" '
        if inStr(files, "INV") then
            'print out 6 times'
        end if
        ' if name contains "PO" '
        if inStr(files, "PO") then
            'print out 2 times'
        end if
next
MsgBox("completed")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Printing PDF files with VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50906669/printing-pdf-files-with-vba)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to documentation (https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/Acrobat_SDK_developer_faq.pdf) you could send a command to print a file, but there is no parameter for the number of copies.

> You can display and print a PDF file with Acrobat and Adobe Reader
>   from the command line. These commands are unsupported, but have worked
>   for some developers. There is no documentation for these commands
>   other than what is listed below.
>
> Note: All examples below use Adobe
>   Reader, but apply to Acrobat as well. If you are using Acrobat,
>   substitute Acrobat.exe in place of AcroRd32.exe on the command line.
>   AcroRd32.exe pathname — Start Adobe Reader and display the file. The
>   full path must be provided. This command can accept the following
>   options.

```
/n Start a separate instance of Acrobat or Adobe Reader, even if one is currently open.
/s Suppress the splash screen.
/o Suppress the open file dialog box.
/h Start Acrobat or Adobe Reader in a minimized window.

AcroRd32.exe /p pathname — Start Adobe Reader and display the Print dialog box.
AcroRd32.exe /t path "printername" "drivername" "portname" — Start Adobe Reader
and print a file while suppressing the Print dialog box. The path must be fully specified.
The four parameters of the /t option evaluate to path, printername, drivername, and portname (all
strings).
printername — The name of your printer.
drivername — Your printer driver’s name, as it appears in your printer’s properties.
portname — The printer’s port. portname cannot contain any "/" characters; if it does, output is
routed to the default port for that printer
```

**For multiple copies of each pdf, you could use a loop.**

Something like this:

```
    set shApp = CreateObject("shell.application")

currentPath = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetAbsolutePathName(".") 

set shFolder = shApp.NameSpace( currentPath )

set files = shFolder.Items()

set oWsh = CreateObject ("Wscript.Shell")
dn = 1 
inv = 6
po = 2

for each files in files
    msgbox(files)

    if inStr(files, "DN") then
        for x = 1 to dn
          oWsh.run """AcroRd32.exe"" /t /n /h /o /s" &files,,true

        next  
    end if

    if inStr(files, "INV") then
        for x = 1 to inv
          oWsh.run """AcroRd32.exe"" /t /n /h /o /s" &files,,true
        next  
    end if

    if inStr(files, "PO") then
        for x = 1 to po
          oWsh.run """AcroRd32.exe"" /t /n /h /o /s" &files,,true
        next  
    end if

next
MsgBox("completed")
```

**Note: tested only with XPS Document writer**

Comment: Hi Mihai Adrian, Thank you for your reply. Im sorry but do how do I integrate it into my code? Im new to vbs so I'm a little lost here. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Thank you very much. :) The only problem now is that I keep getting "access denied" while trying to open the pdf file. However, if I manually open from the adobe reader it works fine. Do you know how to solve this problem?

Comment: If your location is on a network drive you might get that error. Try moving the folder to a local drive. Also, on Acrobat reader: Choose Edit > Preferences.
In the Categories list on the left, select Security (Enhanced).
In the Sandbox Protections section, deselect Enable Protected Mode At Startup.

Comment: *EDIT* THANK YOU :) I've done it. Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad to be of help!